# HTML5 responsive canvas mouse position and resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a drawing interface which the drawings need to be saved at 1280x720px. However, I want the canvas to be able to be scalable in relation to that aspect ratio. A problem is that when I draw, the start of the path is not on the cursor.

I've looked everywhere and cannot find a solution. Here is the javascript:

```js
var clearButton = document.getElementById('doodle-bin');
var canvascontainer = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas-container');
var canvas = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = (document.getElementById('doodle-canvas-container').clientWidth + document.getElementById('doodle-canvas-container').clientHeight)/150;
var dragging = false;

context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

canvas.width = 1280;
canvas.height = 720;
canvas.style.width  = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';

/* CLEAR CANVAS */
function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

var putPoint = function (e) {
    if (dragging) {
        context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        context.lineWidth = radius * 2;
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        context.fill();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    }
};

var engage = function (e) {
    dragging = true;
    putPoint(e);
};

var disengage = function () {
    dragging = false;
    context.beginPath();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', disengage);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following function to get the proper mouse position even if the canvas is re-scaled. This will resolve the path start issue.

```
function getMouesPosition(e) {
    var mouseX = e.offsetX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth | 0;
    var mouseY = e.offsetY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight | 0;
    return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
}
```

---

```js
var clearButton = document.getElementById('doodle-bin');
var canvascontainer = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas-container');
var canvas = document.getElementById('doodle-canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = (document.getElementById('doodle-canvas-container').clientWidth + document.getElementById('doodle-canvas-container').clientHeight) / 150;
var dragging = false;
context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

canvas.width = 1280;
canvas.height = 720;
canvas.style.width = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';

/* CLEAR CANVAS */
function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

function getMouesPosition(e) {
    var mouseX = e.offsetX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth | 0;
    var mouseY = e.offsetY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight | 0;
    return {x: mouseX, y: mouseY};
}

var putPoint = function (e) {
    if (dragging) {
        context.lineTo(getMouesPosition(e).x, getMouesPosition(e).y);
        context.lineWidth = radius * 2;
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(getMouesPosition(e).x, getMouesPosition(e).y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        context.fill();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(getMouesPosition(e).x, getMouesPosition(e).y);
    }
};

var engage = function (e) {
    dragging = true;
    putPoint(e);
};
var disengage = function () {
    dragging = false;
    context.beginPath();
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', disengage);
```

```css
body{margin:0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<button id="doodle-bin">Clear</button>
<div id="doodle-canvas-container">
  <canvas id="doodle-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you

Comment: Saved my day! Was struggling with this for some time, this really comes in handy.